# Java marshaller. Use tag value as attribute value

Tags: java, xml, marshalling

I have the class

```
class Header {

    @FCBTag(type="type1") --My custom annotation
    int a = "valueA";
    @FCBTag(type="type2")
    String b = 1;
    @FCBTag(type="type3")
    Boolean c = true;

}
```

And i want to marshall this class to XML like this

```
<Header>
    <a type="type1" value="valueA" />
    <b type="type2" value="1" />
    <c type="type2" value="true" />
</Header>
```

Is it possible? Is there exists some adapter? And how can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

I implemented support for this into [EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy's)](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) `@XmlPath` extension.  Below is how you would specify the mapping on your class.

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;
import org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.annotations.XmlPath;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
class Header {

    @XmlPath("a[type='type1']/@value")
    int a = "valueA";

    @XmlPath("b[type='type2']/@value")
    String b = 1;

    @XmlPath("c[type='type3']/@value")
    Boolean c = true;

}
```

**For More Information**

There is a complete example for this feature on my blog:

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/03/map-to-element-based-on-attribute-value.html

Comment: Thanks, Blaise. But how can i do with dinamycly type?

Comment: @SerzhanBerdibekov - What is the value of the `type` attribute based on?

Comment: I want to use my annotation for this. Is it possible?